# Lambda expression for .Count()

Tags: c#, .net-core, lambda

I have this method to create custom lambda for OrderBy:

```
public IOrderedQueryable<T> createLambdaOrderBy<T>(IQueryable<T> source, PropertyInfo orderByProperty, bool desc = false) {
    string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    MemberExpression propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    LambdaExpression orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExpression);
}
```

This creates an expression like this

```
.OrderBy(p => p.SomeProperty)
```

But how could I modify it so that, if the property is a collection, it uses count() to order it?

```
.OrderBy(p => p.SomeProperty.Count())
```

Comment: I'm not certain  I understand the question. You want e.g. to order the collection from the least number of items to the most number of items?

Comment: You would need to change `propertyAccess` to be `countOfPropertyAccess` by adding a `Expression.Call` to `Count()` around it. Since `Count()` is either `Enumerable.Count()` or `Queryable.Count()` extension method, it is a static method that has an implicit first parameter that would be `propertyAccess`. I think you would probably use `Enumerable.Count()`, depending on the type of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand properly, but if you want to order by the least numerous to the most numerous collection, you'd do:

```
.OrderBy(p => (p is collection c) ? c.Count : -1)
```

This would put all the non collection first.

If you want all the non-collection last, then you'd do:

```
.OrderBy(p => (p is collection c) ? c.Count : int.MaxValue)
```